# MySQL distinct join with multiple rows null

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a design problem in MySQL. I want to use a view in order to get the records from multiple tables. The problem is that some tables can have multiple rows of data from the same patient while other rows just has one. In order to illustrate this, here are two tables: **bed_billing** and **lab_billing**

[image: bed billing]

[image: lab billing]

Notice the patient_id field. two records for one patient as it is normal. now when it comes to the join, all of these fields will duplicate. that's the problem. I have tried grouping by them, but to no avail. 
this is the query for my view syntax:

```
create view billed AS
select 
   bed.bed_bill_id,
   csr.csr_bill_id,
   lab.lab_bill_id,
   pharm.pharm_bill_id,
   rad.rad_bill_id,
   phys.attending_id,
   bed.price AS bed_price,
   csr.price AS csr_price,
   lab.price as lab_price,
   pharm.price as pharm_price,
   rad.price as rad_price,
   pat.patient_id AS Pid
from
patient pat
     left outer join bed_billing bed
        on bed.patient_id = pat.patient_id
     left outer join csr_billing csr
        on csr.patient_id = pat.patient_id
     left outer join lab_billing lab
        on lab.patient_id = pat.patient_id
     left outer join pharm_billing pharm
        on pharm.patient_id = pat.patient_id
     join rad_billing rad
        on rad.patient_id = pat.patient_id
     left outer join attending_physician phys
        on phys.patient_id = pat.patient_id

where 
     bed.patient_id = pat.patient_id
```

**OUTPUT:**
[image: output]

they have duplications all over the rows. should i just create a transaction table so it stores all of the data in there or push thru with the view? my main assumption is that MySQL fills up the rows in order to fill it with the multiple record rows.

the desired output should be that all ids are distinct and does not duplicate. but when i tried putting distinct in the query, it also duplicates.

**desired output:**

[image]

Comment: use group by bed_bill_id

Comment: I do not see any duplicate. Column `lab_bill_id` is unique at `csr_bill_id` column level. Provide your expected result and please do not provide image for sample data.

Comment: mysql is not equals sq-server. That's why i removed the tag

Comment: @krishnpatel I have tried that also but it still has duplicates.

Comment: @Viki888 Sure. I'll edit it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this:

```
where 
     bed.patient_id = pat.patient_id
```

then use distinct

Comment: I need to have the patient id to select all related data.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: yes i did. still the same. duplication. what i don't understand is even if i use group by, it still duplicates

Comment: Try to use left join not left outer join

Comment: nothing really changed though. they still duplicate

Comment: I think it goes duplicate because you had a null value field as a result i guess. It is because of all price field.